# Locate the nginx.conf file my nginx is actually using

Tags: macos, nginx, system-administration

Working on a client's server where there are two different versions of nginx installed. I think one of them was installed with the brew package manager (its an osx box) and the other seems to have been compiled and installed with the nginx packaged Makefile. I searched for all of the nginx.conf files on the server, but none of these files define the parameters that nginx is actually using when I start it on the server. Where is the nginx.conf file that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 363, accepted):

Running `nginx -t` through your commandline will issue out a test and append the output with the filepath to the configuration file (with either an error or success message).

Answer (score 72):

Both `nginx -t` and `nginx -V` would print out the default nginx config file path.

```
$ nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.11.1
built by gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf ...
```

If you want, you can get the config file by:

```
$ nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -o '\-\-conf-path=\(.*conf\)' | cut -d '=' -f2
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Even if you have loaded some other config file, they would still print out the default value.

---

`ps aux` would show you the current loaded nginx config file.

```
$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root        11  0.0  0.2  31720  2212 ?        Ss   Jul23   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -c /app/nginx.conf
```

So that you could actually get the config file by for example:

```
$ ps aux | grep "[c]onf" | awk '{print $(NF)}'
/app/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 35):

```
% ps -o args -C nginx
COMMAND
build/sbin/nginx -c ../test.conf
```

If nginx was run without the `-c` option, then you can use the `-V` option to find out the configure arguments that were set to non-standard values. Among them the most interesting for you are:

```
--prefix=PATH                      set installation prefix
--sbin-path=PATH                   set nginx binary pathname
--conf-path=PATH                   set nginx.conf pathname
```

Comment: I tried to run the commands but they didn't work for me.. The second anwer works

Answer (score 13):

```
which nginx
```

will give you the path of the nginx being used

---

**EDIT (2017-Jan-18)**

Thanks to Will Palmer's comment on this answer, I have added the following...

If you've installed nginx via a package manager such as HomeBrew...

```
which nginx
```

may not give you the **EXACT** path to the nginx being used. You can however find it using

```
realpath $(which nginx)
```

---

and as mentioned by @Daniel Li

you can get configuration of nginx via his method

alternatively you can use this:

```
nginx -V
```

Comment: "which" works on most Unix based systems. I just typed it on Ubuntu to make sure I hadn't lost my mind.

Comment: oh wow, i stand corrected. modifying the answer right away. thanks

Comment: `which nginx` only shows the *default* path for nginx for the current user (not even the current user - the current *shell*). It definitely does not show the path for which nginx "is being used".

Answer (score 7):

All other answers are useful but they may not help you in case **`nginx` is not on `PATH` so you're getting `command not found` when trying to run `nginx`**:

I have nginx 1.2.1 on Debian 7 Wheezy, the `nginx` executable is not on `PATH`, so I needed to locate it first. It was already running, so using `ps aux | grep nginx` I have found out that it's located on `/usr/sbin/nginx`, therefore I needed to **run `/usr/sbin/nginx -t`**.

If you want to use a non-default configuration file (i.e. not `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`), run it with the `-c` parameter: `/usr/sbin/nginx -c <path-to-configuration> -t`.

You may also need to **run it as `root`**, otherwise nginx may not have permissions to open for example logs, so the command would fail.

Answer (score 5):

for me

```
$ nginx -t                              
nginx: the configuration file /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

$ vim /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: This solution worked best for me. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Daniel Li's answer, the nginx installation with Valet would use the Velet configuration as well; this is found in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/valet/valet.conf`. The `nginx.conf` file would have imported this Valet conf file.

The settings you need may be in the Valet file.

Answer (score 1):

## Let's save a time

you can find your nginx.conf file or any file using mlocate

$ `mlocate` `<any file name or extention>`

$ `mlocate nginx.conf`

## If mlocate package not installed or ERROR: mlocate has no installation candidate

So you should proceed as follows:

$ `sudo apt update`

$ `sudo apt install mlocate`

or

$ `sudo apt-get update`

$ `sudo apt-get install mlocate`

Hopefully, your issue should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Path of nginx.conf in MacOS

```
/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: `/opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (in my case)

Comment: @PallArpad Sure, same to me on MBP M1 on Sonoma. It is `/opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Answer (score 0):

Nginx.conf location in Mac
/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf