# nginx not accepting large body notwithstanding ample large body size

Tags: nginx, passenger, osx-snow-leopard

a rails3.2.18 application via passenger and nginx is generating in nginx log as follows: `2014/10/20 00:31:36 [error] 85#0: *32 client intended to send too large body: 4066821 bytes, client: XX.XXX.XX.XXX, server: app3.iwant2go2.com, request: "POST /bozzadocuments/1 HTTP/1.1", host: "app3.iwant2go2.com", referrer: "http://app3.iwant2go2.com/bozzadocuments/1/edit"`

The error is immediately registered after submission in the log, but the browser is getting a response between 15 and 30 seconds later.
the `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`  file (OSX 10.6) has been edited to allow ample body_size

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    client_body_in_file_only clean;
    client_body_buffer_size 32k;
    client_max_body_size 200m;
    sendfile        on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    send_timeout 300s;

    #gzip  on;

    # Phusion Passenger config
    passenger_root /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/lib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /Users/jeromepmmfcamus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby;
    }
}
```

Where is this configuration going wrong?

Comment: You appear to have an errant '}' in the config you posted? Are you sure that file is correct and being used?

Comment: More than appear.  That is an extra curly bracket.  I had surmised the default parameters were being used and looked - I guess too much - at the http and server blocks...  By your comment I am assuming that there is a way to know which configurations nginx is using at a given instant.  (sorry if this appears as a second question) Although I've removed the errant bracket, I'm still hitting 413 errors. How can one know what configs are in use, if at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19910152/778719

Comment: `nginx -t` returns `-bash: nginx: command not found`, while `ps -o args -C nginx` returns `ps: illegal argument: nginx`

Comment: How were you restarting nginx to reload the new config?

Comment: Sincerely, I was re-booting the machine as `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist` was unreactive.  [just found the solution as passenger nginx install is a different path].  Still, *unhappy* with the feedback from launchctl.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to recall that this installation was done via passenger.

```
passenger-install-nginx-module
```

this installs the nginx.confs under `/opt/`

```
/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

A clue to that would have been to examine the contents of `homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist`... and one would've gotten there faster.